# Search JSON file for exact match only

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I have a jQuery function that searches my .json file. However, because this file is going to have over 100,000 records, I only want to return exact matches. Can someone illustrate how I change my current code to accomplish this?

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('#submit').on('click', function(){

        var searchField = $('#search').val();
        var regex = new RegExp(searchField, "i");
        var output = '<div class="row">';
        var count = 1;
        $.getJSON('myjson.json', function(data) {
          $.each(data, function(key, val){
            if ((val.merchantID.search(regex) != -1) || (val.accountName.search(regex) != -1)) {
              output += '<div class="dataContain">';
              output += '<p><span style="font-weight:bold;">Account Name: </span>'+val.accountName + '</p><p><span style="font-weight:bold;">EMV Status: </span><span class="status">' + val.status +'<span class="circle"></span></span></p>';
              output += '</div>';

              if(count%2 == 0){
                output += '</div><div class="row">'
              }
              count++;
            }
          });
          output += '</div>';
          //$('#results').toggle();
          $('#results').html(output);

        });
        setTimeout(function() {
        $('span.status:contains("Red")').addClass('red');
        $('span.status:contains("Green")').addClass('green');
        $('span.status:contains("Yellow")').addClass('yellow');
        console.log('this function is running.'); 
         }, 100);
    });

  });
```

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, it's as simple as:

`if ((val.merchantID == searchField) || (val.accountName == searchField))`

Comment: Thank you! I was staring at this too long. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either the === [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) for an exact string comparison or [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) for an exact match if you are looking for a match within a string, although if at all possible I would recommend that you use a database or server side language to search your json. Your search is running client side which depending on your users hardware and browser may take quite long. If there is no alternative don't forget to use a loading .gif or show progress so that your page does not seem un-responsive.

```js
'This is my test string'.indexOf('test');
//outputs 11

'This is my test string'.indexOf('testi')
// outputs -1

'This is my test string'.indexOf('TEST')
// outputs -1
```

Comment: Will be using PHP for the live version - this is for a demo using some static data. I really appreciate your feedback. Thank you!

Comment: @shepherdMan1016 if your using PHP and still reading a json file then I reccomend you decode the json as an array and use the function array_search if you want a quick and easy way to get a match.